# Как организовать параллельно выполняемые тесты в WebdriverIO?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, распараллеливание, mocha

В [спецификации](http://webdriver.io/guide/testrunner/organizesuite.html) бегло упоминается ссылка на такой факт:

> Возможно, вы уже поняли, что WebdriverIO создает для каждого
>   spec-файла (или feature-файла в cucumber) одну сессию Selenium. В
>   общем случае, вы должны стараться тестировать одну функцию своего
>   приложения в одном spec-файле.

Однако по самой логике организации mocha-тестов, отдельная сессия браузера нужна каждому блоку `describe()`, которые при этом могут быть и вложенными друг в друга.

Также мне не очень понятно, откуда вообще взят этот факт.

Как на самом деле нужно организовать тесты, корректно работающие параллельно,
т.е. с параметром `maxInstances` большим единицы?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Распараллеливание в WebdriverIO достигается путём *последовательного выполнения отдельных spec-файлов в параллельно запущенных сессиях выбранных браузеров*.

Следует иметь в виду, что с этим сопряжён отдельный класс проблем ChromeDriver, приводящих к массовому crash'у сессий браузеров без видимых на то причин.